# How to do variable substitution in json

Tags: linux, aws-cli

The below table insert command takes a json as an input. I am trying to do variable substitution but it didnt work. What is the right way to do it.

note: echo on numberoflines works.

```
aws dynamodb put-item     --table-name staging-metrics     --item '{ "count": {"S": $numberoflines} }'
```

tried alternatives like "$(numberoflines)" but that stores $(numberoflines) literally in table.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this... but isn't `--item "{ \"count\": {\"S\": $numberoflines} }"`

Comment: Correct. Content in single-quotes will not change, whereas double-quotes will allow variable substitution. See: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697781/174777)